# Last Survivor - codewars

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, indices

So this question is from the Last Survivor kata in codewars. Below is the guideline and an example input.

You are given a string of letters and an array of numbers.
The numbers indicate positions of letters that must be removed, in order, starting from the beginning of the array.
After each removal the size of the string decreases (there is no empty space).
Return the only letter left.

The input should result in the letter following.
last_survivor('kbc', [0, 1]), 'b'
last_survivor('zbk', [2, 1]), 'z'

the issue I am running into has been with 'zbk' with the indices [2,1]. here is my code.
The code is able to solve all others just fine, but for the problem 'zbk' with the index starting with a 2 it states that the list of index in line 6 is out of range. Is this code not reading correctly to pop new_letters[2] then new_letters[1], it does it just fine for the others.

```
def last_survivor(letters, coords): 
    while len(coords) >= 1:

        new_letters = [l for l in letters]
        for i in coords:
            new_letters.pop(coords[i])
            

        return ''.join(new_letters)
    else:
        return letters
```

Comment: change your `while` to an `if` and your `new_letters.pop(coords[i])` to `new_letters.pop(i)` and your solution works. Though it is more complicated than needs be and the solution offered by @Prune is what I recommend as well.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* out of range: did you not trace your logic?  You iterate through the entire `coords` list for *every* element in the list.  In structural terms, you have a nested loop where the problem suggests only one loop.

You also have a serious error in that you take the *value* from `coords`, and then use it as an *index* into the list.

Get rid of the `while`; simply iterate through the given coordinates.

```
new_letters = list(letters)
for pos in coords:
    new_letters.pop(pos)            

return ''.join(new_letters)
```